# Making Mongoose/MongoDB query helper plugin return zero results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm developing a [Mongoose Query Helper](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#query-helpers) plugin that provides the chainable method `.search(query)`. On certain conditions, I want the query to return **zero results**, no matter how the other methods in the query builder chain behave. Turns out this isn't so easy as I have assumed.

Basically, I have the following code:

```
schema.query.search = function search(query) {
    if ("query is invalid") {
        // return no results => no easy way to achieve that?
    }

    return this.find(query);
};
```

Now, I want `SomeModel.find({}).search(someQuery).exec()` to return no results in case the query is invalid. I first tried to `return this.limit(0)`, but turns out a limit of 0 is equivalent to [setting no limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#zero-value).

As a temporary solution, I do `return this.find({ nonExistingField: 'something' })` which always results in no results, but this does seem a bit awkward and is probably also not so optimal in terms of performance as it triggers a search when no search is needed.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: how about returning an object with an exec method? something like `return {exec: (cb) -> cb(null, [])}`

Comment: @MarcoGabrielGodoyLema , thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, your suggestion is not working when there are other chained methods following my `.search(query)`, e.g. `.search(query).count().exec()`. :-/

Comment: How about `.skip(Infinity)`?

Comment: `.skip(Infinity)` didn't work, but after I read [this](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate/issues/114), I tried `.skip(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)` - this works! However, according to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/), skip is often expense (has to walk through the collection before beginning to return results). Is there really no better solution?

Comment: well ... stopping the chain would be the best one :P ... I don't think there is a good way to go to the database and tell it to do nothing. Just throw an exception.